# Angular distinguish route from paremetrized route

Tags: angular8

I have an Angular 8 app. In my router module I have something like this

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: ':code', component: CodeComponent },
      { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent},
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
    ];
```

The problem here is that when I access (for an example) `/not-found` the component `CodeComponent` activates, but not the `NotFoundComponent`.

I want to distinguish `/not-found` page from parametrized `/:code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the order of your routes in your array so the `'not-found'` definition comes before the `':code'` definition. Like this

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent},
  { path: ':code', component: CodeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: I did not know that the order matters, I'm still a beginner. Thank you